# Cylinder set but not rectangular cylinder set in a product $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i, \mathcal{A}_i), i\in I$ be measurable spaces. Define the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{A} = \times  \mathcal{A}_i$ for ${i\in I}$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that the coordinate map $X_i$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{A}_i$measurable for each $i$. For $J\subset I$, define $\mathcal{A}_J=\times \mathcal{A}_j$ for $j\in J$.

Klenke ("Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course") defines a cylinder set with base $J$ as $X_J^{-1}(A)\subset \Omega$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}_J$, where $X_J$ is the coordinate map to $\times\Omega_j$ (${j\in J}$). Then, he calls $X_J^{-1}(A)$ as a rectangular cylinder set if $A=\times A_j$ ($j\in J$) for some $A_j\in\mathcal{A}_j$.

My question is, is there an example of a cylinder set that is not a rectangular cylinder?

After some thinking, I realized that if $J$ is finite, then $\mathcal{A}_J=\sigma(\times A_j,{j\in J})$, so I guess for a finite $J$ all cylinder is rectangular cylinder?

Comment: The true statement in your last sentence does not help to get to the bottom of the question what a (rectangular) cylinder set is. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set) all cylinder sets are in fact rectangular in the sense of your quote from Klenke. Are you sure Klenke does not assume the $A_j$ to be intervals which makes the cylinder set intuitively more like a rectangle, cube, hypercube?

Comment: Ah I see Wikipedia defines a cylinder set as $X_{J}^{-1}(\times A_{j},j\in J,J\subset_{\text{finite}}I)$ so according to that definition there should be no distinction. I see what you're suggesting but I'm sure Klenke does not specify $A_j$ to be intervals or to have some specific structure for that matter. All he says is that $A$ can be written as a Cartesian product.

Comment: Seems like Klenke tried to be too good by calling it "rectangular" cylinder set. Follow the  math and don't let you being confused by words.

Comment: @keepfrog I'm currently reading Klenke's book and have the same question you asked. Was the conclusion you reached that Klenke does not assume the set $J$ to be finite? In other words and $J$ is finite $\Leftrightarrow$ the cylinder sets are rectangular?

Comment: @CBBAM My conclusion is that there is no distinction between cylinder set and rectangular cylinder set as they are defined. I read through the rest of the book but the distinction of the two never came up. Regarding your interpretation, I don't think so, because then the definition in the next page does not make sense.

Comment: @keepfrog Thank you for your response. I guess I won't worry about it too much and will let $J$ be infinite. In other words, I think of a cylinder set as the preimage $\pi^{-1}_J(A)$ where $\pi_J$ is the projection map from the whole space to a $|J|$ many components and $A$ is a set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by taking $J$ products of the measure space. Is this the right way to think of it?

Comment: Yeah but I think it's practical to think that $J$ is finite. The typical use of cylinder sets is that we show some property for $\mathcal{Z}^R$ (eq. 14.3) and then we use Theorem 14.12 (ii) to argue that the property holds for the product sigma-algebra. Each element in $\mathcal{Z}^R$ is the preimage of finite-dimensional projection.